# MSP430 LCD Interfacing via I2C

Tags: lcd, msp430

I am new at this. I am trying to interfacing 1602A LCD display with MSP430G2553 via PCF8574. When I run the code, nothing happens:

```
#include <msp430.h>

unsigned int *ptxData;
unsigned int count = 0;
// [0..3] -> power on, [4..5] -> function set, [6..7] -> display off, cursor off, blink off
// [8..9] -> clear screen, [10..11] -> right, do not shift, [12..13] -> display on, cursor on
// [14..15] -> write char 'B'
unsigned int txData[] = {0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x24, 0x22};

void main() {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;

    // for i2c pins
    P1SEL = 0xC0;
    P1SEL2 = 0xC0;

    // i2c config
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;
    UCB0CTL0 = UCMST | UCMODE_3 | UCSYNC;
    UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_3;
    UCB0BR0 = 12;
    UCB0BR1 = 0;
    UCB0I2CSA = 0x27;   // slave address
    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;

    // enable tx interrupt
    IE2 |= UCB0TXIE;
    _enable_interrupts();

    // start to transmit data
    ptxData = txData;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;

    while (1);
}

#pragma vector = USCIAB0TX_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCIAB0TX_ISR(void){
    // send txData elements one by one
    UCB0TXBUF = *ptxData;
    count++;
    *ptxData++;

    // if txData ends, start from beginning
    if (count == 16) {
        count = 0;
        ptxData -= 16;
    }
}
```

What am I missing, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is obviously missing comments what it does. If it did have comments what it does or what it is supposed to do, it would be more clear to find out what's wrong.

First of all the transmit data pointer is initialized to null, so it is sending garbage data instead of data from the transmit data array.

Second problem is that the array contains only command nybbles that must be sent to LCD. They are just loaded to GPIO expander data pins, but the LCD RS, RW and E lines are not set at any point for each command nybble, so the commands are not strobed to the LCD.

Comment: Right, I should have added comments, my mistake. I fixed the data pointer. But I2C bus is 8-bit. If I add RW, E, RS bits, data length will be 10-bits. How can I send 10-bits?

Comment: The LCD is connected with 4 data bits to the expander. Three other expander bits are the LCD control bits. There is one bit left which is either not used or is controlling the backlight. Just see the expander module schematics.

Comment: I edited and added comments. Now, I am sending data by RS + R/W + DB7/4 then RS + R/W + DB3/0. But nothing happends except the screen goes on and off at uncertain times.

Comment: At least it does something. Maybe you are not toggling E correctly?

Comment: Toggling E? How can I toggle E? Sorry, I am new at these.

Comment: You have two different problems. It does not matter which one you solve first. One problem is how to set and control any of the GPIO expander pins to whatever state you want. The second problem is, how you need to know how you must drive the LCD pins to write something to it correctly. And thus, you need to know which IO expander pin is connected to which LCD pin. Perhaps you have documentation or schematics of the I2C expander board, or datasheet for the I2C expander chip. And some datasheet for the LCD display.